# Do Oddities glow through walls while using the scanner?

Tags: warframe

I am trying to collect the Oddities in Warframe, but I don't want to look up all of the locations. Do the Oddities glow while looking through the scanner like other scan-able objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a few threads I've looked at, it looks like Oddities (also called Kuria) are scannable and do glow.

From [here](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=508828282):

> Like most scannable objects, unscanned Kurias also glow when aiming with the scanner (the glow however is golden like unscanned enemies and not green). Already scanned Kurias won't get highlighted on your scanner anymore.
>   The scanning range is 50 meters, any Kurias (and objects in general) further away than that will neither be highlighted nor will you be able to scan them.

And from [here](https://forums.warframe.com/topic/285621-oddity-thread-gotta-find-em-all/):

> Since the Kuria show up on the scanner, it is very easy to find them by scanning a room and looking for their distinctive shape and yellow image in the scanner HUD.